# Is this question still too broad?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, close-reasons, reopen

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149004/ was put on hold as too broad, but edited the same day. Now it's been on hold for a few days. Is it still too broad?

Comment: For those with <10k rep, the question [can be viewed here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RhFQV.png). A newer version of the question can be [found here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149893/wave-equation-variables-and-matrix-interpretation).

Answer (score 2):

Questions that are edited after they are closed enter the reopen queue. There has not been a single reopen queue cast on that question, indicating that the reviewers still thought it too broad.

My personal view is that this is a mixture between *too broad*, *unclear what you're asking* and *non-mainstream*:

You just throw the matrix exponential in there and essentially ask "Is this a wavefunction?". I bet one can write down something looking like a wave equation to which that exponential would be the solution, but what do you *mean* by *"[...]is there a natural way to extend the previous wavefunction interpretation[...]*"? What *was* the previous wavefunction interpretation? (Just writing down an exponential doesn't make it a "wavefunction"!) Why would you expect the matrix exponential to have the same interpretation? What system are you trying to model? It's really not a very focused question.

Comment: In the scalar-variable case, _k_ is the wavenumber. In the vector-variable scalar function, _k_ is the wave-vector. Since we can define the same function with matrix variables, it seems valuable to ask if some properties of a matrix _k_ (norm, eigenvalues, etc.) determine the behavior of the system in an analogous way as the scalar and vector _k_'s. You say: "_Just writing down an exponential doesn't make it a "wavefunction"!_. Very good! Please don't stop there but answer the question. A good answer to the question would illustrate why this particular function _is_ or _isn't_ a wavefunction.